# How can I launch an OSX application from the browser?

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I'm coding an admin panel with a web interface that will only be run locally (not client-facing or hosted on an external server), and it would be helpful if it could launch an application from an `<a href="">`. Is this possible? I understand that this could be a browser security thing, but I also know that there are iTunes and App Store links (not quite sure how those work either), and I assume this is also possible for launching "x" application. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution! Instead of using an `<a href="">`, I've decided to run a shell command from a PHP script that just does `open application_name.app` and redirect back to the referrer.

Answer (score 1):

it is only possible if the application you want to start registers its own URI scheme with the OS. Though you could write your own app that starts other apps on demand. You'll have to [register your own scheme then](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).